# Applying discrete calculus to prove the results of the classical calculus

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, discrete-calculus

Can the discrete calculus be used as a way of proving theorems of the classical calculus? For example, isn't the following a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus by means of the discrete calculus?

The discrete derivative can be defined as:

$\Delta f(x) = {f(x+h)-f(x) \over h}$

Similarly, the discrete integral can be defined as:

$\sum\limits_{x:a \to b} f(x) = hf(a) + hf(a+h) + hf(a+2h) + ... + hf(b-h)$

And here's a some kind of the fundamental theorem of calculus in the discrete world:

$\sum\limits_{x:a \to b} \Delta f(x) = (f(a+h)-f(a)) + (f(a+2h)-f(a+h)) + ... + (f(b)-f(b-h))=f(b) - f(a)$

Isn't the following true in such case?

$\int\limits_a^b f(x) dx = \lim\limits_{\lambda(P) \to 0} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(\alpha_k) \Delta x_k = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \sum\limits_{x:a \to b} f(x)$

Another example. Isn't the following a proof of $(e^x)'=e^x$?

$\Delta a^x=a^x$

${a^{x+h}-a^x \over h}=a^x$

$a^x a^h - a^x=ha^x$

$a^h-1=h$

$a=(1+h)^{1 \over h}$

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} (1+h)^{1 \over h} = e$

$f'(x)=\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \Delta f(x)$

$(e^x)'=e^x$

Edit.

As was noted, the Dirichlet function gives a counterexample:

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \sum\limits_{x:a \to b} \chi_\mathbb{Q}=0$

While the Dirichlet function doesn't have a Riemann integral. However, the Dirichlet function does have a Lebesgue integral equal to zero. Would the above formulas be correct if we'll restrict $f$ to only functions continuous over $[a,b]$?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've only seen "discrete calculus" used to describe the situation you've given with $h=1$. As soon as you start taking the limit $h \to 0$ I think you're not doing much different from the standard calculus presentation...

Comment: @Shaun, thanks for the suggestion. I've changed the title to "Applying discrete calculus to prove the results of the classical calculus". Hopefully it's precise enough now.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks! Yes, my thoughts originate from this article on the discrete calculus: http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/DCalc.pdf, where the author describes the case of integers (i.e. $h=1$). So I've been wondering if the same method could apply to prove the classical calculus theorems.

Comment: Such approaches are at a best a futile approach to treat calculus as fancy algebra. A similar but rigorous approach is infinitesimal calculus/non-standard analysis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you got it backwards. Because claiming that something is equal to something in a limit is weaker then assume it to be true even without the limit.  So starting out with $\Delta a^x = a^x$ is a stronger assumption then saying $(a^x)' = a^x$. Like $x_n = 0$ is much stronger then $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0$. Because assuming the former you will say, well $x_n = 0$ thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n = 0$. But that is not the general case as you know. Am I wrong with that?

For the Riemann integral I think you can see that it can't be true in general, because you just claim you can look at one particular case of a tagged partition. But that is not true. You must have it for any partition and any points. Take the Dirichlet function as a famous counterexample.

So assuming you know the classical results you can also say something meaningful also in the discrete case. The opposite is not true in general.

What do you think? I am still a little bit fuzzy but my "spider senses" just tell me something need to be off.

*edit:*

Here, let it make me precise in case of the indicator function on $\mathbb{Q}$ denote $\chi_\mathbb{Q}$. If we would have
$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx = \lim_{h\to 0} \sum_{x:a\to b} f(x),
$$
then 
$$
\int_0^1 \chi_\mathbb{Q} dx = 0.
$$
But using the "right" definition of the Riemann integral via the Riemann sum and all possible tagged partition will show that this function is not Riemann integral (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Examples)) for Details why that is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your counterexample indeed shows that it's not the Riemann integral. However, what if we'll restrict $f$ to only functions continuous over $[a,b]$? Would it work then? Are the above formulas correct when the Riemann integral does exist?

Comment: In that case I think you can use those formulas. Note that is also what you want from the definition of the integral. It really shouldn't matter what kind of partition you use. So knowing you have a limit for any tagged partition you of course can choose one. Also note that I am *not* saying that what you wish to do can not be done. It is just note that easy in general. But there very well might be nice proves using these kind of discretetizations. Maybe checkout @ParamanandSingh suggestions.